# Remote attribute in editor template in asp.net mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have the following two properties in Country class (Model).

```
public class Country
{
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Remote("CheckName", "Country", AdditionalFields = "Id")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Above I am expecting `Id` to be passed to `CheckName` method.
I have the `CheckName` method in `CountryController` as:

```
public JsonResult CheckCountryName(string Name, int Id = 0)
{
     return Json(!repository.Countries.Where(c => c.Id != Id).Any(c => c.Name == Name), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am using editor template for Country class, `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Country)`

Id property is being rendered as hidden field by id as Country_Id and name as Country.Id. When I am editing Name field, `CheckName` is not getting the required values (name gets null and Id gets 0 (being the default value))

I checked in Fiddler, request is going to server as `GET /Country/CheckName?Country.Name=abc&Country.Id=0 HTTP/1.1`.

What should I do to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my method and used Bind attribute and it works now.

```
public JsonResult CheckCountryName([Bind(Prefix="Country")]Country oCountry)
{
     return Json(!repository.Countries.Where(c => c.Id != oCountry.Id).Any(c => c.Name == oCountry.Name), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's passing your model through. So your `JsonResult` should be using your model, `Country`, not Name and Id individually.

Like this:

```
public JsonResult CheckCountryName(Country country)
{
     return Json(!repository.Countries.Where(c => c.Id != country.Id)
                 .Any(c => c.Name == country.Name), 
                 JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: not working, country.Id is coming as 0 and country.Name is coming as null

Comment: I just created a test on my machine and it works fine. How are you submitting your data?

Comment: the request is coming as : GET /Country/CheckName?Country.Name=abc&Country.Id=0 HTTP/1.1